# Как записать количество символов в строе, в конец каждой строки

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Дан файл, содержащий несколько строк. Нужно записать в конец каждой строки количество символов данной строки. Я могу результат вывести на экран, но как в конце каждой строки этого же файла написать сколько символов в этой строке!

Вот до чего я додумался:

```
Program   еxample_3; 
Var  f:   Text;
x,  k:  Integer; 
c:char;
Begin
  Assign (f, 'w:\info\pascal\pr.txt'); 
         {Связываем  файловую  переменную с файлом  на  диске}
  Reset (f);         {Открываем файл для чтения} 
  x:=0;                {Обнуляем счетчик строк}
  While  Not  Eof(f)   Do   {Пока  не достигнут  конец  файла} 
  Begin
    k:=0;                 {Обнуляем счетчик    элементов   строки}
    inc(x);               {Увеличиваем счетчик строк}  
    While  Not Eoln(f) Do {Пока   не достигнут  конец  строки} 
       Begin 
         Read(f, c) ;      {Считываем очередной символ} 
         Write(c,'  ');    {Выводим его на экран} 
         Inc(k);              {Увеличиваем счетчик символов} 
       End;
    Writeln( ' В  ',x, ' строке ', k, ' элементов') ; 
    Readln(f);             {Переходим к следующей строке файла} 
  End;
  Close(f);     {Закрываем файл}    
  Readln; 
End.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в чём проблема? Открываем файл для чтения, читаем строки из файла в цикле (можно создать массив строк), определяем длину строки с помощью функции Length (также можно создать массив длин строк). Если использовались массивы, то открываем этот же файл для записи, и в цикле записываем в него прочитанные строки и через пробел их длины (требуется перевести число в строку). Можно массивы не использовать, а во время чтения из одного файла, нужную информацию вносить в другой.

Comment: Не могли бы вы без массива решить задачу

Comment: @марат1994, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.